# What is the meaning of new int[25,2]?

Tags: c++

What is the meaning of using the second parameter with a comma in the below code?

```
int *num = new int[25,2];
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly legal code (unfortunately)

Comment: But notice that `new (int[25, 2])` is not legal code.

Comment: @Johannes: Did you mean `new int(25, 2)`? Oh, wait, is `new (int [25])` and `new int (25)` equivalent?

Comment: @Lazer no i meant what i wrote.The expression inside the brackets is required to be a constant expression then, but `25, 2` does not syntactically match it and neither semantically. So even if you write it as `new (int[(25, 2)])` it is illegal code. Doesn't need a comma operator to explain it - even `int n = 1; new (int[n]);` is illegal - `n` isn't a constant expression.

Comment: @litb, although in C++0x, `25, 2` is a constant expression and `new (int[25, 2])` does compile.

Comment: @avakar correct, in C++0x it's a constant expression. But the syntax wasn't changed :( So you still can't write that, but have to write `new (int[(25, 2)])` :(

Comment: @litb, it seems you're right, the grammar indeed requires parentheses (though it seems to be an omission to me). By the way, msvc10 accepts the version without the parentheses.

Comment: @avakar so does comeau - it allows any non-constant expression :) gcc (with -pedantic) warns about a VLA being created if you take parentheses, and errors out without parentheses. Clang rejects by syntax error for without parentheses, and rejects with "when type is in parentheses, array cannot have dynamic size" when in parentheses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's the [comma operator](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/The-comma-operator.html) in action: it evaluates it's operand and returns the last one, in your case 2.
So that is equivalent with:

```
int *num = new int[2];
```

It's probably safe to say that the `25,2` part was not what was intended, unless it's a trick question.

Edit: thank you Didier Trosset.

Comment: Does the comma operator return the first operand or the last one?

Comment: This looks alot like Didiers answer.. Did you use the same source, or do programmers just think alike :)

Comment: Nice copy-paste. Might want to fix the grammar next time ;)

Comment: @Peter Alexander: Might want to check the 'answered x mins ago' part ;)
I've thanked Didier for pointing that it returns the last not the first like I initially said.

Comment: if nobody has overloaded this operator (i don't know, if it possible for integer).

Comment: @Lonli: It is not; at least one operand has to be a user defined type.

Answer (score 15):

That's the comma operator in action: it evaluates it's operand and returns the **last** one, in your case 2. So that is equivalent with:

```
int *num = new int[2];
```

Comment: Please note that the text of the posts on SO is published with a license that requires attribution. You may copy-paste, but you should cite the sources.

Comment: Eugen Dinca posted the exact same answer 2 minutes before you. I'm not sure re-posting his answer just to correct one word is more efficient (and more elegant) than just pointing out the error so he can fix his answer.

Comment: I didn't thought I could edit others' answers. I actually first pointed the error in a comment, you can see it, and a couple of minutes after copied-pasted his answer to correct it. With my apologies for the non correct behavior.

Answer (score 10):

You are using the comma operator, which is making the code do something that you might not expect at a first glance.

The comma operator evaluates the LHS operand then evaluates and returns the RHS operand. So in the case of `25, 2` it will evaluate `25` (doing nothing) then evaluate and return `2`, so that line of code is equivalent to:

```
int *num = new int[2];
```

Answer (score -1):

// Declare a single-dimensional array
        int[] array1 = new int[5];

```
    // Declare and set array element values 
    int[] array2 = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

    // Alternative syntax 
    int[] array3 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    // Declare a two dimensional array 
    int[,] multiDimensionalArray1 = new int[2, 3];

    // Declare and set array element values 
    int[,] multiDimensionalArray2 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

    // Declare a  array 
    int[][] Array = new int[6][];

    // Set the values of the first array in the  array structure
    Array[0] = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```